# how update cached data when main data is change in laravel

Tags: laravel, caching, redis-cache

i want to use a cache of laravel for ex: index method on a specific controllers!
i use Cache::rememberForever method of laravel cache.

i dont use Cache::remember with ttl time for caching data!

my question: i dont no when and how i update data in cache

imaging: i cached user profile with all relations! now user change avatar or personal data! now i should be renew (update) cache data in redis! (update cache data for get in next call) i want to know the best solution for updating cache data when update main data

Comment: How you can do this really depends on how you implemented the caching.

Answer (score 2):

To update a cache you can use such. event function in your User model:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    $removeCacheFunc = function ($model) {
        $key = self::USER_CACHE_KEY . $model->id;  //compile cache key in your way
        \Cache::delete($key);
    };
    static::saved($removeCacheFunc);
    static::deleting($removeCacheFunc);
}
```

Next time you call `Cache::rememberForever()` will not find this entity by key and will make it on the fly